# highlight text contained in multiple adjacent elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a JavaScript search application that takes a text string and breaks it into multiple parts using spans.  A separate function will search either on the entire text or only in one of the previously identified sections.

My problem is that when I attempt to highlight the text after I identify the sections.  I can't figure out how to highlight the text contained in multiple spans.

For example if I have the string.

```
<div id="container">
  <span id="sectionOne">This is my first section</span> 
  and 
 <span id="sectionTwo">This is my second section</span>
</div>
```

how would I highlight `section and This` which is contained in both spans as well as a text element?

Thanks for any help. If it is possible to do this in pure JavaScript that would be most helpful; although, any solution is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
<div id="container"> <span id="sectionOne">This is my first section</span>  <span id="sectionTwo">This is my second section</span>

</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

JS

```
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var src_str = $("#container").html();
    var term = $('#search').val();
    term = term.replace(/(\s+)/, "(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
    var pattern = new RegExp("(" + term + ")", "gi");

    src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
    src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/, "$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

    $("#output").html(src_str);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/nw83T/)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This answer works for highlighting strings in individual spans.  Although, it doesn't seem to work if I want to highlight a string that appears in adjacent spans.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get something to work by parsing the string and storing the various parts in a object with the position values.  When I want to search on an individual section I simply search within my object then replace the correct part of the original input.

I am sure there is a better way to solve the problem but breaking up the string into an internal object was the only way I could get this to work.